# Tips on approaching a flutter app which uses website data and features

Tags: database, flutter, webserver

I am new to app development and I am thinking about creating an app which will store all the anime that you are currently watching or have watched in the past. The purpose of this app is to store your progress of an anime/manga so that if you forget which chapter you were on the last time you watched/read the anime or manga.

My plan is to connect this app to myanimelist website and use its feature on my app to find an anime. Then if the user adds the anime to his watch-list then it will store the important data e.g., name, description, author, Image.

I am totally new to app development and I have to create an app for the final year project. As on how to start the app or the resources required I am at loss.

The main topic of my concern is on how I should handle the use of website data or the connection to the database. Is something like using SQL queries? Which database should I use to store the data on local device?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions

1. how I should handle the use of website data or the connection to the database.

   if You have an API that you are using for your website, then you can use that API to fetch data in your flutter app.In case your don't have an API you have to create one for your app.
2. Which database should I use to store the data on the local device?

   For storing data to the local device you can use sqflite package for flutter to store data. Using sqflite you can write simple SQL queries to fetch or store data in the
   database.

Ask if you have any problems.

Comment: Thanks, I will let you know if any questions arise.